# Как вызвать события из функции

Tags: c#, winforms

Как вызвать события из функции? Есть событие у формы, как его вызвать из другой функции?

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Что написать в тело?

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ?????
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
private void SomeMethod()
{
  ...
}

private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SomeMethod();
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SomeMethod();
}
```

Comment: Я хочу вызвать Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e), в событии button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: @MegaRoks Нет, не хотите.

Comment: Окей, спасибо ))

Answer (score 1):

самый простой способ - это передать null в качестве аргументов, если, конечно, вы не используете их в коде

```
Form1_Shown(null, null);
```

Comment: Можно дополнить ответ: `Form1_Shown(this, EventArgs.Empty)` если null-овые значения не подходят.

Comment: Вот только это вызов обработчика события,  а не самого события. Если на form1. Shown подписаны другие обработчики - вызов в них не дойдет.